# Prevent RecyclerView to change position when loading additional items

Tags: android, chat, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with `setStackFromEnd(true)` representing a chat list. And I want to load older messages when the list is scrolled to the top. I managed to do this using onScrollListener.

But when I add items to the adapter with `messages.addAll(0, aListWithNewMessages)` (messages is data set for adapter) and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, new list items (as expected) appear before the existing ones and shift them down (not the experience a user wants), and I want to add them silently so a user shouldn't see it.

So my guess for how to tackle this issue is to scroll list to somehow previously saved position.

I understand that this is not a bug or an unexpected behavior, so please help to sort it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try being more specific. Instead of calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` use `notifyItemRangeInserted` or similar `RecyclerView` methods. That will allow `RecyclerView` to know what to do and will provide much better UX.

Comment: This is the correct solution. Telling RecyclerView the range to insert an item to avoids scrolling the RecyclerView.